# UNIX SAS connectivity with SQL SERVER Window Authentication

Tags: sql-server, unix, odbc, sas

I have a UNIX SAS and SQL Server on Windows XP. I am trying to make a connection between UNIX SAS and SQL Server in Windows Authentication Mode. I made an ODBC Connection but when I try to connect using the following command:

```
libname odbclib odbc noprompt="dsn=SQLDataODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes" schema=DBO;
```

I got the following error:

```
"ERROR: The ODBC engine cannot be found."
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have the `SAS/Access to ODBC` product installed on your UNIX server.  That is a separately licensed product and not part of "base" SAS.

If you think you might want to add this product, contact your site administrator.  If you will be mostly dealing with `SQL Server`, consider adding the `SAS/Access to SQL Server` product instead.

Comment: When I try it to connect with SQL Server 97 it got connected but only problem with SQL Server 2005.Any Idea on it?

Comment: It that case, you must have `SAS/Access` installed, so you either have a configuration error in your ODBC.ini file or you need an updated ODBC driver.  To get better help, open a SAS Tech Support ticket here:  http://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform/createForm.  They can help troubleshoot your configuration.